# Rails: Reason log config shows difference between console and logfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, console

I have a Rails 3 app.
Using the default logging config, when I issue a command like

```
logger.warn "some message"
```

Logger message appears in console and in logs.

Now I add one line to production.rb

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log","biteme.log"))
```

Logger message does not appear in console, only the logs.
Then I change it to this:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first)
```

And now message appears in console and in logs. There is some knowledge here that I am missing, because it does not make sense why the first config omits log message going to console. Any ideas?

Comment: first object is a String, second object a Path, I guess the behavior of the logger is conditionnal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails actually now uses `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` instead of ruby's standard `Logger` class.

Try making your custom logger of that class and see if it works:

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(Rails.root.join("log","biteme.log"))
```

Comment: I have used this now as it seems to be the rails standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got down to the root of the problem. I was using a jasonp gem that conflicted with the logs in Heroku. Locally, no problem (of course) but running from Heroku, the log messages did not appear. When I removed that gem - log messages appear on Heroku.
Am a happy camper now.